# Concatenar valores en vba con un for

Tags: excel, vba

tengo el siguiente código:

```
 For periodo = 2020 To 2022
        NombreProtegido = "@@" & periodo & "@@ HojaAdministrativa"
        If IsEmpty(Range("C15").Value) = True Or LCase(Range("C15")) = LCase(NombreProtegido) Then
            MsgBox ("Tienes que seleccionar una hoja válida")
        End If
    Next
```

Lo que hace (o me gustaría que hiciese) es que tengo hojas que se pueden llamar "@@2020@@ HojaAdministrativa" , "@@2021@@ HojaAdministrativa" etc. y este código es para una macro de eliminar hojas. Entonces en una hoja en particular, el usuario ingresa (con una lista) en la celda C15 el nombre de la hoja a eliminar, pero quiero que las hojas administrativas no pueda borrarlas.
Si quito el For y fijo el valor dentro del @@, por ejemplo:

```
If IsEmpty(Range("C15").Value) = True Or LCase(Range("C15")) = LCase("@@2020@@ HojaAdministrativa") Then
   MsgBox ("Tienes que seleccionar una hoja válida")
End If
```

Sí funciona a la perfección, pero si hago que recorra diferentes valores me surgen dos problemas:

1. Excel elimina la hoja y luego me salta el mensaje de "Tienes que seleccionar una hoja válida" algo que no tiene sentido porque ya me ha borrado la hoja.
2. Me saltan tantos mensajes de "Tienes que seleccionar una hoja válida" como valores recorra el for.

Espero que me puedan ayudar
Gracias.

Comment: Quita de esa lista en C15 las hojas que no quieres que se borren. Y en relación al 2º punto, tu msgbox está dentro del bucle, por eso repite.

Comment: Al tener el msgbox dentro del bucle provocas eso mismo, tantos mensajes como elementos recorras. Teóricamente, si la hoja no es válida ya no debería continuar por lo que puedes meter un "Exit Sub" debajo de MsgBox ("Tienes que seleccionar una hoja válida").

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, ya lo he solucionado!